# View plugin in java template engine

Tags: java, spring, template-engine

Is there any posibility to define view plugin in spring mvc that would render some template with custom logic, and call it from any template where it’s needed. For example consider plugin which is indicating logged in username

Comment: Can you describe your use case a little more?

Comment: I'd like to provide functionality to render some block of data backed by some model, on couple different pages without worrying about retrieving retrieving the model data in each action method. What I want to achieve in the simplest case is class with one method 'render' with should retrieve data from db and render it with some preconfigured template. I want to be able to call this method from any template and each time it should return rendered html